# How to check if code that is run belongs to active sheet

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have written some code for an excel spreadsheet. This sub has been added to the ribbon using the standard customizations found in File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon. What is funny though, is that the customization will run the Sub on the EXACT EXCEL FILE that the Sub is written in, i.e. the original.

My users copy the excel file and make adjustments and then run the sub (by clicking the customized button in the ribbon), which then opens the ORIGINAL template file and runs the code. This actually works fine - and I like it because it runs the TEMPLATE code on the ACTIVE sheet. But the only problem is it is also OPENING the original template file. How do I get it to close? Remember it is not the ActiveSheet anymore.

One possible answer is to check if the template is open, then close it (using a static reference), but I would prefer something a little more elegant than that.

Comment: I suppose when VBA programming elegance is kinda left at the door...

Comment: I am sorry, I dont have excel 2007/10. Is it possible to assign the macro to the button, asking it to scope it as `RunMacro` instead of `MyWorkbook.xlsm!RunMacro` in the original workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the template/original using `ThisWorkbook`.

---

Also, if you deliver your workbook's code as a .xlam instead of .xlsm, it will be opened, but there won't be a window for it, so users won't see it.

---

Not sure if you're using this already, but you might also want to use "for this workbook only" when adding ribbon buttons for a .xlam .  (Delivering as .xlam allows you to install buttons from a workbook into the ribbon, without relying on file path and without needing your users to also install buttons (they install .xlam instead).)